# How to extract XML data from Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm trying to extract XML data from feedback table consist of message column; below is the XML code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>Hi Hello</message>
<channel>XYZ</channel>
<sentiment-score>5.0</sentiment-score>
<structured-fields>
<structured-filed><name>NA_score</name><value>5</value></structured-filed>
<structured-filed><name>NPS_score</name><value>10</value></structured-filed>
<structured-fields>
```

I need to extract the above XML code from message column.

Comment: please add your comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document needs to have a [single XML element as the document root](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <message>Hi Hello</message>
  <channel>XYZ</channel>
  <sentiment-score>5.0</sentiment-score>
  <structured-fields>
    <structured-field><name>NA_score</name><value>5</value></structured-field>
    <structured-field><name>NPS_score</name><value>10</value></structured-field>
  </structured-fields>
</root>
```

Once that is fixed then just use an `XMLTable` and XPath:

```
SELECT *
FROM   XMLTABLE(
         '/root'
         PASSING XMLType( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root><message>Hi Hello</message><channel>XYZ</channel><sentiment-score>5.0</sentiment-score><structured-fields><structured-field><name>NA_score</name><value>5</value></structured-field><structured-field><name>NPS_score</name><value>10</value></structured-field></structured-fields></root>' )
         COLUMNS
         MESSAGE         VARCHAR2(200) PATH '//message',
         CHANNEL         VARCHAR2(200) PATH '//channel',
         SENTIMENT_SCORE NUMBER(3,1)   PATH '//sentiment-score',
         NA_SCORE        NUMBER(3,0)   PATH '//structured-fields/structured-field[name/text()="NA_score"]/value',
         NPS_SCORE       NUMBER(3,0)   PATH '//structured-fields/structured-field[name/text()="NPS_score"]/value'
       );
```

**Output**:

```
MESSAGE  | CHANNEL | SENTIMENT_SCORE | NA_SCORE | NPS_SCORE
:------- | :------ | --------------: | -------: | --------:
Hi Hello | XYZ     |               5 |        5 |        10
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=432d845a5cc8f2083fe626e626995c55)*